# how can I move yAxis labels from Right of chart to left of chart in highstock

Tags: charts, highcharts

how can I move yAxis labels from Right of chart to left of chart in highstock.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKtpc/4/) example in which we have labels like `Fresh Breeze` on the right side of chart which I want it on the left.

In the previous version of Highstock it is was on left by default.
I have also tried the property `align:left` inside the `yAxis` options but it does not give the desired result.

Thanks

Comment: Align left looks like working, just changed one of that options for "High wind", and looks perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/LKtpc/26/ ...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You don't want to set align:left at the axis level, you need to use it on the plotband label level.

The code in that example is explicitly telling the chart to align the plot band labels to the right, and push them an extra 40 pixels right as well.

Change that to `align:left`, and `x:0`

(or, just don't set the align or x properties at all, and by default the labels will be on the left, as they've always been...)

example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/LKtpc/28/

**{{EDIT:**

Your original question referenced the plotband labels in highcharts...

But it seems your question is really about the y axis placement in Highstock.

To move it to the left, you need to add this:

```
yAxis: {
  opposite:false
}
```

as Highstock sets the axis to `opposite:true` by default.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/aayajgLe/1/

Comment: it is not on left by default in the latest version of highstock

Comment: Ok, but your example wasn't in Highstock :) Does the answer fix your problem, or is there more? If you're using highstock and still having a problem, post your example using highstock and we can figure it out.

Comment: I just picked up this example from Highstock website. Have a look http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/

Comment: you question was originally referencing plot band label alignment. I am very confused as to what you are actually asking at this point. See updated answer for more info.

Comment: yes your updated answer is what I was asking for. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

In order to put your yAxis label to the left side, just set yAxis' opposite property to false.

```
yAxis: {
  opposite: false
}
```

It seems not intuitive, though.